# App is not visible in App Store for iPad

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, app-store, appstore-approval

I have the application. This application supports iPhone only, but I can launch it on iPad. In itunesconnect I see "Your binary doesn’t support iPad. The screenshots or app video preview for iPad won’t be shown on the App Store."

So as far as I understand I shouldn't see screenshots for iPad, but I should see the application in App Store (when I look at it from iPad).

**But when I search for my application in iPad I can't find it there (but for iPhone everything is OK). Why?**

Comment: iPad can launch your app but that is 4x view not compatible for iPad. that app is iPhone app and you can see this app as a iPhone app not iPad. And if you are not upload for Universal then how can that appear on iPad side and its screenshot and video

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When search app in ipad version app store there are two categories: ipad only and iphone only. You'll find your iphone only app in iphone only category.

to change category there is navigation item button the left most one

Answer (score -1):

If your application supports only iPhone in your project's Devices in General Tap then it will be available only for iPhone devices in the AppStore. You can build and run your project in iPad either from xCode or with TestFlight but it will run as if it was an iPhone app in x2 or x1 mode depending on the iPad's screen resolution.

Comment: it's not true, please see the answer above